# Closable tab with tab item being a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I am working on a project in C# WPF. I have a tab container and I want to dynamically load different types of tabs into the tab container as the user requires. As an example I am doing something like the following:

```
tabContainer.Items.Add(new MyUserControl());
```

I want each tab to have a close button so the tab can be removed the container when the user no longer requires it.

I found [this code project example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem) but from what I can see you are a loading a user control which contains the xaml for the tab itself, not the tab content or am I missing something.

How can I load in my User Control into the tab container, but also have the tab closable.

Currently the tab that I am loading in uses some static binding to set the tab title using the following:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabContainer" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,45,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.55" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

My user control then has a `public string TabHeader{get;set;} which gets set in the constructor depending on what constructor of my user control is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define the close `Button` yourself. You could for example do this in the `HeaderTemplate` of the `TabItem`:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabContainer">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            <Button Content="x" Click="Button_Click_2"
                                            Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

The `Tag` property is bound to the `UserControl` in the `Items` collection which you can remove in the click event handler of the `Button`, like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabContainer.Items.Add(new MyUserControl());
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        tabContainer.Items.Remove(button.Tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks for that. I've never managed to get my head round everything you can do with `DataTemplates`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a close button to each tab, that would be in the TabItem style ControlTemplate. Normally you'd specify the data context (i.e. the data *only* that's driving the content) in Content and then specify the look in ContentTemplate. If your Content is a UserControl then you don't specify the ContentTemplate since a UserControl knows how to draw itself.

Answer (score 0):

For my sins, I've added close-tab buttons to the WPF TabControl. I ended up putting the close button in the ItemTemplate. Here's a minimal version that works with the way you're populating the TabControl and the header content:

```
<TabControl
    >
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label
                    Content="{Binding}"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    />
                <Button
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                    <Path
                        Data="M 0, 0 L 12, 12 M 12,0 L 0,12"
                        Stroke="Red"
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        Width="12"
                        Height="12"
                        />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <local:UserControl1 TabHeader="First Item" />
    <local:UserControl1 TabHeader="Second Item" />
</TabControl>
```